# Matrix report with columns grouped with Date field has strange column added

Tags: custom-reports

Hi so my question is what is this strange column i can see after i group my columns with Date?

[image]

I do not know what it shows and why it is there. How to remove it?

Comment: Looks like you may have a record with a null Date field. If you filter the report for Date != null, does it go away?

Comment: null is not good value for filter with date my friend :( I managed to add empty date but it didn't filter them out.

By the way the field Date is required

Comment: the `Date` field may be required now but perhaps at some point in the past it was not

Comment: I did check and there are no record with empty date field